# The version of mobile showcase

Tags: dojo, version

Currently I'm using DOJO 1.9 to develop, but it seems not run on IE. But I see that in the showcase run well with IE. I don't see the version of dojo.js using with showcase. Could you tell me the version of DOJO using in the mobile showcase?
http://demos.dojotoolkit.org/demos/mobileGallery/demo-iphone.html

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check dojo version, open your console and type dojo.version

In this case it's 1.8.0r30226